# Retrieve whether a subscriber has been added to a suppression list or not

Tags: marketing-cloud, soap-api, suppressionlist

I'm trouble understanding how to retrieve whether or not a subscriber has been added to a suppression list or not. Please note that I'm referring to a regular suppression list, not an auto-suppression list.

Currently using the following envelope body to retrieve list statuses on subscribers, however the response from this call does not return any information on any suppression lists the subscriber has been added to:

```
 <soapenv:Body>
  <RetrieveRequestMsg xmlns="http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI">
     <RetrieveRequest>
        <ObjectType> ListSubscriber </ObjectType>
        <Properties>CreatedDate</Properties>
        <Properties>SubscriberKey</Properties>
        <Properties>ID</Properties>
        <Properties>ListID</Properties>
        <Filter xsi:type="SimpleFilterPart">
           <Property>SubscriberKey</Property>
           <SimpleOperator>equals</SimpleOperator>
           <Value>{{SubscriberKey}}</Value>
        </Filter>
     </RetrieveRequest>
  </RetrieveRequestMsg></soapenv:Body>
```

Is there another body I should be using to retrieve this information?

Comment: Your SOAP looks fine. Stupid question, but what's the value of "{{SubscriberKey}}"? Is there a subscriber on the exclusion list with that value?

Comment: Yes, the subscriber key is just the value of the subscriber key for a subscriber that has been added to a suppression list.